# SPFX - After import babel-polyfill in my webPart(IE Issues)

Tags: sharepoint-server, spfx, sharepoint-framework

I use react-table which does not work in a **Internet Explorer 11** and I need  to install  babel-polyfill into my project(web pack);

**[This is issue in github](https://github.com/react-tools/react-table/issues/340)**

I follow this steps:

**1)** npm install --save babel-polyfill

**2)** import at the top "babel-polyfill" (in my web part which use react-table)

**Before import** *polyfill* conponent doesnt render into a page and has no errors(*Only in IE, in others browsers works*):
[image]

**After import** *polyfill* into my entry point class i have following error(*Only in IE, in others browsers works*)
[image]

Comment: any idea where is a problem?

Comment: can you import the react table as `import ReactTable from 'react-table/lib'` and check ?

Comment: I import ReactTable from 'react-table/lib', but has no difference. The table is not displayed under IE! Please help...

Answer (score 2):

I had run into same issue what you are facing.
The issue is resolved now.
steps are
Don't import the babel-polyfill
Add the below to your webpart class
  - import 'core-js/es6/number';
  -import 'core-js/es6/array';

Answer (score 1):

you should add a `require('babel-polyfill');` or a `import 'babel-polyfill'` (or indicate a submodule if you don't want all the polyfills) in your webpart class (all the way at the top).
If there's no import/require, webpack module loader won't bundle and then load it because "it doesn't know it's needed"

Comment: Seen my updated answer!